# this is not a vector space,is it?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

One of my tutorial question is this

$V = [0,\infty)$. For $x,y ∈ V, α ∈R,$ deﬁne $x + y = xy$, $αx = |α|x$

V is vector space or not ?

Zero vector of this becomes '$1$'.and addittive inverse of $x\in V$ is $\frac{1}{x}$.Since $0$ is inluded in $V$, for $0$,there is no addittive inverse since there exist no $ y\in V$ such that $0*y=1$,So i think this is not a vector space

is there any wrong with my argument?is this a vector space?

Comment: Yes, you are right: $(V,+)$ has to be an abelian group.

Answer (score 1):

For all $x \in V$, we have $0 = 0x = (1-1)x = 1x + (-1)x = x + x = 2x$ so that $x = 0$. Also $0$ has no additive inverse, as you said.